# How to properly use a forward declared class in c++ cli?

Tags: c++-cli, forward-declaration

I am getting error code C2512 which is no appropriate default constructor available. However it appears to me that everything should be working so I am a bit confused on how to get this to compile.

Here is the header file code:

```
namespace MyNamespace
{
   ref class ForwadDeclaredClass;

   public ref class MyClass
   {
      public:
         MyClass();
         // ...
      private:
         ForwadDeclaredClass^ fc;
   }
}
```

Now in my cpp file I define the forwarded class and try to use it in the constructor for MyClass.

```
using namespace MyNamespace;
//...

public ref class ForwardDeclaredClass
{
   public:
      ForwardDeclaredClass()
      {
      }
}

MyClass::MyClass()
{
   // Compiler complains with error code here
   fc = gcnew ForwardDeclaredClass();
}
```

I know I have to be missing something simple but I am just not seeing it. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

At first glance, it looks like your namespaces are off.

In the header file, you're declaring `ForwardDeclaredClass` and `MyClass` inside `MyNamespace`.

In the cpp file, you're *using* `MyNamespace`, but the code you're writing isn't *inside* the namespace.

It looks like you need to enclose most of the contents of the cpp file in a `namespace MyNamespace {` block.

Comment: Not *most* of the code, but just the definition of `ForwardDeclaredClass`. The forward-declaration is made for `MyNamespace::ForwardDeclaredClass` because the `ref class ForwadDeclaredClass;` line is inside the namespace, but the definition is for `::ForwardDeclaredClass` (it's outside of the namespace). No need to wrap the `MyClass::MyClass()` definition inside a `namespace` block - `using namespace MyNamespace;` is in effect there.